Unreliable firestore onSnapshot() listener on iOS
I’m using firebase's onSnapshot() listener in my js for a website.
const unsubListener = onSnapshot(doc(db, "collectionName", "documentID"), (doc) => {
   // render data as html elements 
   …
}); 

On Windows and Android (Browsers: Chrome, Edge, Firefox) it works fine, displaying all changes.
But on iOS it seems to work reliable only when the browser stays open. When I move the browser (tested on Safari and Chrome) to the background, make some changes to Firestore like
updateDoc(doc(db, “collectionName“, „documentID“), {…})

and bring the website back to the foreground it unreliably displays these changes.
Sometimes changes are displayed immediately, sometimes 10sec after opening the browser and sometimes even longer.
I found two similar questions (Firestore listener delayed when coming from background in iOS & onSnapshot appears to stop working after a period of time) but the solution was (to detach and) reactivate the onSnapshot-listener. This would work, but disturbs the user experience as it would re-render all items and I depend on only updating changes (except on first call). Additionally I would like to know what‘s the problem currently and not only resolve the symptoms
I hope there are enough details now, otherwise I would appreciate what I should add. Logs are showing nothing odd.
